# Excel 2013 vba file error when I open in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have .xlsm file, that has been saved in Excel 2013.
When I open the file in Excel 2010 and try running the code, I get an Error: "can't find project or library", And the "Date" function marked as problem.

Comment: You have a reference problem. What references do you have checked in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel 2013 uses the excel 15.0 library, whilst 2010 uses 14.0. Unfortunately, vba is not backward compatible. You can try to uncheck the invalid excel library and assign the 14.0 again in 2010 (in the VB editor: Tools -> References)

Comment: You cannot change the Excel reference in an Excel workbook, nor would you ever need to because that **will** adjust automatically.

Comment: Respectfully, this answer cannot possibly be correct.